# UILongPressGestureRecognizer and Annotation doesn't work on the users location when it is showing on the map Swift

Tags: swift, annotations

I am trying to drop an annotation on a users location in a mapview using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. I can drop annotations anywhere else in the mapview, except the users location. The users location is visible using `mapView.showsUserLocation = true`.

Any tips? I want my user to know where they are in relation to the map, AND, be able to use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` on their current location. I am stuck! I am coding in Swift and X-Code Version 6.3.1
Some code I am using:

```
var uilpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "action:")
uilpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2
mapView.addGestureRecognizer(uilpgr)
mapView.showsUserLocation = true

//later on in action method
var touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.mapView)
/* a bunch of code to extract the coordinates */

var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `userLocation.title = ""` in `mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation!)`

ex:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation!) {
    // your code
        userLocation.title = ""
    }
```

So callout of userLocation will never show and you can use long press near user position too.

Comment: Thanks for this. I moved my 'mapView.showsUserLocation = true' from my viewDidLoad() into my existing locationManager function:

       'func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
//my code + below
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.userLocation.title = nil
}'

that did it for me. much appreciated.